# Azure AD : can an access token for a given application be used to retrieve an access token for a different application?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

Considering that the Azure AD underneath the 2 applications is the same it makes sense that this should be possible however I'm unsure on how this could be achieved? Any suggestion?

Comment: What does it mean by "retrieve an access token for a different application"? Please provide more details. Maybe an example?

Comment: Access tokens contain claims that might be things such as permissions or scopes or applications/apis + permissions on those applications. In the context of an application where your code is running you might be able to retrieve a token that proves you successfully authenticated but might not contain the claims/permissions you are after. And example could be the access token that code running within Microsoft Teams can access that however might not enable your to consume services (e.g. microsoft graph) you are interested in. Owning an access token can you get another with going thru auth ?,

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token).

The app can use this token acquire additional access tokens after the current access token expires. Refresh_tokens are long-lived, and can be used to retain access to resources for extended periods of time.

So you need to get the refresh token when you request the first access token.

Then you could use this refresh token to acquire a new access token for another resource (or scope).

// Line breaks for legibility only

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh      // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded
```

You should modify the `scope`. If your first access token is for resource Microsoft Teams, you could now modify the `socpe` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. Then you will get an access token for accessing Microsoft Graph resources.

Answer (score 0):

The OIDC flow that you are describing is called [on behalf of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

There is a MSAL sample that covers it: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph